# I'm Trying To Render A Blue Square In Java But I Am Getting A IllegalStateException Error. Can Someone Help Me?

Tags: java, eclipse, game-development

I was trying to render a blue square in java to the screen but the blue square isn't being displayed and I am getting an `IllegalStateException`.

CreateWindow class

```
package Graphics;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreateWindow {
    
    
    public CreateWindow(int width, int height, String title) {
        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        JFrame frame;
        
        
            d.width =  width;
            d.height = height;
            
            frame = new JFrame();
            
            frame.setPreferredSize(d);
            frame.setMinimumSize(d);
            frame.setMaximumSize(d);
            
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setTitle(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            new BufferedImageOperation();
        
    }
    
    
    public void deleteWindow() {}
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CreateWindow(500,500, "POOP");
    }
}
```

BufferedImageOperation class

```
package Graphics;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class BufferedImageOperation extends Canvas {
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public BufferedImageOperation() {
        render();
    }
    public  void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return; 
        }
        
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

This is what the console is saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:4106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4080)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4608)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3943)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:195)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3867)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:170)
    at Graphics.BufferedImageOperation.render(BufferedImageOperation.java:17)
    at Graphics.BufferedImageOperation.<init>(BufferedImageOperation.java:12)
    at Graphics.CreateWindow.<init>(CreateWindow.java:30)
    at Graphics.CreateWindow.main(CreateWindow.java:39)
```

Comment: I just edited it. Like this?

Comment: Why is it that people who are so quick to vote to close a question, never vote to reopen it??? The original question included an [mre] which although not mandatory for a question is always helpful. The question clearly states the requirement and gives the problem. Yes, the stack trace was not included with the original question, but the OP listened to the suggestion and included the trace. So why haven't you given the OP the courtesy of voting to re-open the question? Or better yet if you don't have the time to reopen questions, maybe you shouldn't vote to close them in the first place!

Comment: Override the `void paint(Graphics g)` method

Answer (score 2):

important to know where the Exception is being thrown, but I suspect that `BufferedImageOperation` is  not visible, not added to any (visible) component,
 e.g: `frame.add(new BufferedImageOperation());`.

Edit: checking documentation of `createBufferStrategy()`:

> throws `IllegalStateException` - if the component is not displayable

and of `isDisplayable()`:

> A component is made displayable either when it is added to a displayable containment hierarchy or when its containment hierarchy is made displayable. A containment hierarchy is made displayable when its ancestor window is either packed or made visible.

Comment: This is how you would do custom painting when using AWT. I believe you do this as painting on a Canvas using a BufferStragegy will reduce flicker when using animation. I'm not sure it does. But I would agree stick with doing custom painting in the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel` (or JComponent) for a Swing application..

Comment: You are correct, I didn't not mean to imply this is the "standard" way to do custom painting using AWT. You suggested you have not seen the approach of using a BufferStrategy. I did mean to imply that I have seen suggestions from people doing game development (or animations) to use a BufferStrategy. The OP tagged the question with "game-development" indicating they do intend to create a game, which would imply that this approach is valid. But of course your original comment about adding the component to the frame is valid whether using a BufferStrategy or overriding paint().